# Magento - 404 error while viewing the module

Tags: magento

i have created module named helloworld in magento, based on the below URL instructions

http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/

Once created everything i can able to enable the module in admin page. But when i type the below URL to my browser it throws 404 Not found

```
http://localhost/magento/magento3/index.php/helloworld/
```

Thanks in advance. Please help

Comment: Please give more info What exactly you do in your module. If You are beginner then refer this blog its give you detail knowledge about module creation :http://www.excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-blogs/module-development-series/

Comment: i have followed the instructions which are given in: http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2009/06/08/create-new-module-helloworld-in-magento/

Comment: Clear catch and then check it.

Answer (score 0):

As you already mentioned, you simply forgot to clear the cache, so Magento did not recognize your extension.

If you run into this issue again, you should also have a look at your ACL definitions. If you have none, your admin user is probably not allowed to use your extension in this case you need to define a ACL rule. Check `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController::_isSectionAllowed()` for details.